# screen resolution and scrolling bar

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html, resolution

Currently I am practicing create a web site by using visual studio.

Q1)  I have a text on top of my screen in master page, when I use width:100%, btn down there will appear a scrolling bar for me to scroll left and right (The thing is on my right of my page is nothing). May I know how to remove it?

Q2)  May i know how to set the web page is fix to the resolution to `1027 x 768` automatically?

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tokipatrick/k9mstd6b)

Thanks for the help! Your comment and suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: make a js fiddle so we can test

Comment: @Hanoncs here u go http://jsfiddle.net/tokipatrick/k9mstd6b/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Use the following CSS and see updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5et6q7p0/)**.

HTML:

```
<div id="user2"> <a id="User"><asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="User" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #User {
        Height:47px;
        float:left;
        text-align:left;
        padding-top:6px;
        font-family:Calibri;
        font-size:25px;
        background-color:grey;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Question 2: Set width of div to `1024px`;